# Angular password varify message

Tags: angularjs

*The code now match very well the password but when I type in the field password, then below the input of confirm password immediately appears the message that the password does not match, when the user write down again the password the message disappear that is fine, but I would like to receive another message like: "Password match!"(in green color!), how can I do that? I read for options like dirty and touched but I could not fix it.*

```
 @* PASSWORD CODE Below--------------<<<<<>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> *@

         <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">

             <label for="password"><font style="color:red;">*</font>Password</label>
             <input data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Minimum 8 characters long and should contain at least one (small- and capital letter, number and special character)." type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeypress="capLock(event)" class="form-control" ng-model="mAddEditView.User.Password" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/" required />

             <div id="divMayus" style="visibility:hidden">Caps Lock is on.</div>
             <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
         </div>


         @* PASSWORD Confirm CODE Below--------------<<<<<>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> *@
         <div class="fieldWrapper" >
             <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password1.$dirty && form.password1.$error.required }">

                 <label for="password1"><font style="color:red;">*</font>Confirm Password</label>
                 <input data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="The password should match." type="password" name="password1" id="password1" onkeypress="capLock(event)" class="form-control" ng-match="mAddEditView.User.Password" ng-model="mAddEditView.User.Password1" required />
                 <div id="divMayu" style="visibility:hidden">Caps Lock is on.</div>

                 <span ng-show="form.password1.$dirty && form.password1.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
                 <span ng-show="mAddEditView.User.Password !== mAddEditView.User.Password1 " class="help-block"><font style="color:red;">Password is not valid!</font></span>


                 </div>

             </div>
```

Comment: So, you already have `ng-show="mAddEditView.User.Password !== mAddEditView.User.Password1"`to show a message when the passwords don't match, and you're asking how to add a message when the passwords match. How about `ng-show="mAddEditView.User.Password === mAddEditView.User.Password1"`?

Comment: No No i that way the message of the "Password Match " will be always there even if the both field are empty that means they are equal right?

Comment: Then how about adding a condition checking that they're not empty: `&& mAddEditView.User.Password.length > 0`. This is quite simple stuff. You should be able to figure that out by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `form.field.$valid` and `$touched` to display password match

```
<span ng-show="form.password1.$touched && form.password1.$valid" >Password Matched</span>
```

Comment: Super, thank you! But now when I write the password appears the message but if I delete 1 digit immediately appears the "password is invalid" but the "Password Match " is still there below the message "Password is invalid" it would be good if I delete 1 digit again to appear the message INVALID but the message Match to disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: `<span ng-show="form.password1.$touched && form.password1.$valid && mAddEditView.User.Password === mAddEditView.User.Password1" >Password Matched</span>` Try this